# Make ArrayList<LinkedList<String>> into an Iterable

Tags: java, iterator

I have an `ArrayList<LinkedList>` and I want to make one `Iterator` for all the `LinkedList`s.

What is the best way to do this?

I found this:

```
  'final Iterable<Integer> all =
  Iterables.unmodifiableIterable(
  Iterables.concat(first, second, third));'
```

But I have many `LinkedList`s. What can I do to combine all of them?

Thanks!

Comment: Use Guava's `ListMultimap`

Comment: I need more javas way. I cant use this libary

Comment: Well, Guava is a Java library...

Comment: isn't your Iterables already guava's `Iterables`? and why  in your question title, you wrote `<string>` but in your codes, you used `<Integer>'?

Comment: This is what I found in the internet...

Comment: @Kent is right, `Iterables` is Guava. So, use Guava!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear whether you want to do this using only standard Java classes, but if so, you can do it this way as of Java 8:

```
ArrayList<LinkedList<String>> strings = /* ... */;
Iterator<String> i = strings.stream().flatMap(l -> l.stream()).iterator();
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple solution

```
    ArrayList<LinkedList<String>> l1 = ...
    List<String> l2 = new ArrayList<>();
    for(List<String> e : l1) {
        l2.addAll(e);
    }
```